# Firefox and SSL pages - takes very long on certain sites

Tags: firefox, ssl, browser, ssl-certificate

I use openSUSE 13.1 and Firefox 38.0.1.

On some pages with ssl it takes minutes until the connection is established. 
It only happens on sites whose ssl certificate is not trusted by firefox, so that it asks you if you really want to enter the site. But even this security question takes minutes until it appears.

In chrome everything works fine.

So what's wrong with firefox? How can I debug this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why, but I removed the file cert8.db from within the profile folder, now it works again.